# MSBUild .NET 6.0 constant not work anymore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I try to convert My project to .NET 6. (I was in .NET 4.7.2 before.)

I'm really surprised that all PostBuildEvent not work anymore
I've got :

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release $(ProjectDir)..\..\Param\PostBuild\TestWebDriver1.cmd $(ProjectDir) $(OutDir) $(TargetFileName)
```

It's seems the constant name has changed :

```
$(Configuration) => $(ConfigurationName) 
$(ProjectDir)    => $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)
```

I found two correspondence, but no doc to find the others.
Any link of doc or maybe something I missed !

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would always compile in latest Net version.  Than Target Net 6.

Comment: Hmm, no, that hasn't changed.  These are internal msbuild variable names, they have been around forever.  Look at an ancient file like C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets for example.  They are intentionally undocumented.

Comment: You can refer to the pages about Common macros for MSBuild commands and properties( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-170 ) and MSBuild reserved and well-known properties( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2022 ). 

Regarding your PostBuildEvent not working anymore, I think it's caused by spaces in the path ” $(ProjectDir) $(OutDir) $(TargetFileName)”. You can delete the spaces and try again.

Comment: Thanks for answer I already look he documents.  
The space was intentional (they was passed to .cmd)  

If I try  
echo "$(ProjectDir)" > D:\temp\t.txt  
I've got ""

echo "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" > D:\temp\t.txt  
I've got the root folder path !